# How would my role as a contractor differ from my permanent position?

Tags: software-industry, contracting

I am, and for the last 7 years have been, a permanent employee of some type of digital agency or software house. I've worked for 4 companies and have a good idea of what's expected of me when joining a permanent role as a developer.

Hypothetically speaking, if I were to leap into contracting, what may I find different about my role? So far I've considered:

- In reality, I must be able to resolve problems myself without leaning on permanent employees much (if at all - since it's *my* service I'm delivering)
- I must 'hit the ground running' and skill-up fast enough to add value from as early as possible

Note: I'm not asking about contracting life outside of the workplace

Comment: Addendum to excellent answers below--you may have to purchase and/or license hardware and software.

Answer (score 5):

No, or minimal, benefits. Price your services to make up for what you're missing. Health insurance, in the US, is the largest but not only issue.

No promise of continuous work. Price your services to provide a buffer if you can't line up another gig immediately after this one.

Remember that you have to spend hours finding that gig. Price your services to cover those hours too; they are part of your cost of doing business

There are many past comments here about consulting, and probably more on the entrepreneurs area of SE. Plus lots of other good reading out there. Get in the habit of doing your own research rather than asking others to point the way, or you won't survive as a consultant.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally, your role will be identical, however, there will be several things that change about the work environment:

1. Few to no benefits
2. Less job certainty.  when budget cuts come, you're likely the first to go.
3. Higher standards required of you
4. You will be more closely monitored
5. Your contract length will be limited by local laws and company policy.  Companies have gotten sued by contractors who have been on site for more than 2 years, so now many have policies that say you cannot work as a contractor for more than X months before they let you go.
6. Unions.  You will likely not get jobs in union shops.
7. Often treated poorly and scapegoated.  It is very common to blame the contractor, especially after you've left.  Be very aware of your reputation.
8. More freedom.  You can schedule your vacations around your contracts
9. More money.  Contractors and consultants make more money.  If you don't need to buy your own benefits, you can make a much higher rate (and you should adjust your rate up by at least 30% to make up for what they are not paying you in benefits.